# beautifulsoup - find all li within div

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

say I have html code

```
<li> ... </li>
<li> ... </li>
<div class="one">
    <ul class = "two">
        <li> ... </li>
        <li> ... </li>
        <li> ... </li>
        <li> ... </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

how would I find all of the li attribute that is in the div tag, but not that is outside the div tag?

```
data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "one"}).find_all("li")
```

but this does not work

Answer (score 2):

> Beautiful Soup supports the most commonly-used CSS selectors. Just pass a string into the [`.select`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method

```
In [25]: soup = BS("""<li> ... </li>
<li> ... </li>
<div class="one">
    <ul class = "two">
        <li> ... </li>
        <li> ... </li>
        <li> ... </li>
        <li> ... </li>
    </ul>
</div>""")

In [26]: soup.select("div  ul")
Out[26]: 
[<ul class="two">
 <li> ... </li>
 <li> ... </li>
 <li> ... </li>
 <li> ... </li>
 </ul>]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may construct an `xpath` selector using the `lxml` module (which you most likely have already installed, since you are using BS), like so:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring(html_string)
items = root.xpath('.//div[@class="one"]/descendant::li')
```

The downside (or maybe an upside really?) is that `xml_string` needs to be a valid html.